# Group by varchar in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query.

```
SELECT  
         sa.start_time,
    `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday`, `Friday` 
FROM ( 
  SELECT  ders_saat,
         (CASE WHEN days= 1 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Monday`, 
         (CASE WHEN days= 2 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Tuesday`, 
         (CASE WHEN days= 3 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Wednesday`, 
         (CASE WHEN days= 4 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Thursday`, 
         (CASE WHEN days= 5 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Friday`
      FROM ders_programi
      inner join lessons d on d.id = lesson_id

) AS sums
left join hours sa on sa.start_time = sums.ders_saat
```

Result: 5 rows

```
start_time  Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday
08:00:00    Math    0         0         0       0
08:50:00    null    null      null      null    null                        
09:40:00    Math    0         0         0       0
10:30:00    Prog    0         0         0       0
10:30:00    0       Geo       0         0       0
```

The result I want: 4 rows

```
start_time  Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday
08:00:00    Math    0         0         0       0
08:50:00    null    null      null      null    null            
09:40:00    Math    0         0         0       0
10:30:00    Prog    Geo       0         0       0
```

How can I do this? I've tried `group by start_time` and `concat` but it didn't work.

I used group by 4 rows return. But last row: `10:30:00  Prog    0         0         0       0`

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code, if appropriate. Otherwise, look at MAX(CASE...). And if you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  sa.start_time,
        max(`Monday`) as Monday,
        max(`Tuesday`) as  Tuesday, 
        max(`Wednesday`) as Wednesday,
        max(`Thursday`) as Thursday,
        max(`Friday`) as Friday 
FROM ( 
  SELECT  ders_saat,
         (CASE WHEN days= 1 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Monday`, 
         (CASE WHEN days= 2 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Tuesday`, 
         (CASE WHEN days= 3 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Wednesday`, 
         (CASE WHEN days= 4 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Thursday`, 
         (CASE WHEN days= 5 THEN d.lesson_name ELSE 0 END) AS `Friday`
      FROM ders_programi
      inner join lessons d on d.id = lesson_id
) AS sums
left join hours sa on sa.start_time = sums.ders_saat
group by sa.start_time
```